# How to dynamically change search parameter in angular algolia instant search

Tags: angular, algolia, instantsearch

I am using `<ais-configure [searchParameters]="{ aroundLatLng: '0, 0' }"></ais-configure>`, and dynamically updating the `{ aroundLatLng: '23, 90' }` object based on user's input, but I can not see any change in search result.

Here is an example, I prepared in codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/kxqxr0j45r

In this example, you can see initially, I added the following search parameter:

```
searchParameters = { hitsPerPage: 3 };
```

And there is a button named "Update Search Parameter", and when you click on that button, it changes the search parameter such as -

```
updateParameter() { this.searchParameters.hitsPerPage = 10; }
```

I am expecting that any change on searchParameters should reflect on the search result. And according to this, I should see 10 results per page. But it is not working.

Would you please tell me how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to trigger the search. Have you tried completing [this tutorial](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/guides/angular-integration.html#install-instantsearchjs) where it says:

*"After you have installed InstantSearch.js to your application’s dependencies, we need to instantiate the InstantSearch.js library into an Angular service."*

Then you can leverage the instantsearch service in AppComponent:

```
...
import { InstantSearchService } from './services/instantsearch.service';
...
export class AppComponent {
...
    updateParameter() {
        ...
        this.instantSearchService.search.start(); // trigger the search
    }
}
```